# Inserting a column before every row and copying header

Tags: vba, excel

I am an extreme newbie here with what is a probably a very rudimentary question, so please bear with me.

I have a worksheet with that looks something like this:

```
product ID  desc    color   length  width
2           a       black   5   
3           b               4       7
4           c       brown   8       9
5           d       red             7
6           e                       4
7           f       pink    6       1
```

I am trying to write a macro that would insert a column before each attribute (such as desc, color etc.) and then filling that column with the header of the column following it.

The result should like this:

```
product ID       desc       color         length        width
2           desc a    color black  length 5       width 
3           desc b    color        length 4       width 7
4           desc c    color brown  length 8       width 9
5           desc d    color red    length         width 7
6           desc e    color        length         width 4
7           desc f    color pink   length 6       width 1
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: On a lighter note... "so please `bare` with me." This is something I don't do ;) I can `bear` with you though :) On a Serious note. Welcome to the forums. You are more likely to get help if you show us what have you tried and where are you stuck.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

This will work as long as your sheet starts as shown in cell `A1`.

I went down the path of iterating through the header range for quite some time and could not make it work since inserting a column to the left would either shift the entire header range over one or add an empty column into the range, and the next iteration of `For Each` would be working with the newly inserted blank column...

I don't like how using counters you have to use the `colCntr - 1` business inside of the loop, but if you read carefully and envision the `Range` offsets, it will make sense (and most importantly, get the desired outcome!)

Long story short, using counters and iterating backwards worked in about half as much code. :)  There may be a less "loopy" way to do this, but I was stumped:

```
Sub SpecialColumnFormatting()
Dim rng As Range, rngCol As Range
Dim lastCol As Integer, colCntr As Integer
Dim lastRow As Long

'get last row and column
lastRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
lastCol = Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column

'grab last col #
colCntr = lastCol

'have to loop backwards
Do Until colCntr = 1

    'insert a column to left
    Range("A1").Offset(0, colCntr - 1).EntireColumn.Insert (xlShiftToRight)

    'you may have to pick this one apart a bit to see what I'm doing
    Set rngCol = Range(Range("A1").Offset(1, colCntr - 1), Range("A1").Offset(lastRow - 1, colCntr - 1))

    For Each rng In rngCol

        rng = Range("A1").Offset(0, colCntr).Text

    Next rng

'decrement
colCntr = colCntr - 1
Loop

End Sub
```